# After upgrade to Ember v11, {{input}} value binding doesn’t work

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, htmlbars

I wanted to update my Ember CLI version from 0.1.15 to 0.2.3 today. Part of this, of course, came with upgrading to the new HTMLBars rendering engine. However now, I'm seeing some very odd behavior in that my `{{input}}` helpers are no longer binding to computed properties correctly when passing them to value. Instead, they are being evaluated as strings, even though they don't contain quotes. For example:

`{{input type="text" value=deviceId}}`

Literally gets displayed as a text box with a value equal to the string deviceId, not of the actual computed property. The weird thing is, when I use the deprecated valueBinding instead of value like this:

`{{input type="text" valueBinding=deviceId}}`

It works fine, but throws a deprecation message. I wasn't able to find anyone else experiencing a similar issue. Would anyone have ideas on what could be the issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you create a dummy ember-cli project do they still not work?  I'm curious if a helper or add-on is foo-baring it

Comment: Just a quick hint - always try to use ember-debug.js version, so you can more easily spot any deprecations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{input type="text" value=model.deviceId}}
```

I recently updated one of my projects and prefixing with the model did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on. I was using `ember-easyForm`, which overwrites the `input` helper explicitly. EasyForm does not yet support Ember 1.11, and is known to break `{{input}}` across the application outside of a `{{#form-for}}` as described [here](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-easy-form/issues/196)

Comment: One could hardly imagine a better example of why it's a bad idea to use every library that comes your way, especially when they don't appear to be actively supported, make poor design decisions such as overwriting core Ember functionality, and contain commit messages such as "Mega hacks to ensure keyword is setup for child view".

Comment: @torazaburo couldn't agree more, but there doesn't seem to be many options out there for good ember form libraries. Have you found anything that helped you with this?